# Ordenar de mayor a menor en java con Quicksort

Tags: java

Tengo el codigo que ordena de menor a menor pero lo necesito de mayor a menor, no se como hacerlo.

```
public static int[] ordQuicksortAsc(int[] datos, int izq, int der) {
    int pivote=datos[izq];
    int i=izq;
    int j=der;
    int aux;
    while(i<j){
        while(datos[i]<=pivote && i<j){
            i++;
        }
        while(datos[j]>pivote){
            j--;
        }         
        if (i<j) {                                
            aux= datos[i];
            datos[i]=datos[j];
            datos[j]=aux;
        }
    }
    datos[izq]=datos[j];
    datos[j]=pivote;
    if(izq<j-1){
        ordQuicksortAsc(datos,izq,j-1);
    }   
    if(j+1 <der){
        ordQuicksortAsc(datos,j+1,der);
    }
    return datos;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! dime por favor que probaste invertir el simbolo de mayor y menor en el sort